# Azure Bot project with client and server in same web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, azure-active-directory, botframework

I've made an Azure bot application using the BotFramework v4 and used the [WebChat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) as an interface. I noticed that the bot server's dotnetcore app had a wwwroot folder with a placeholder HTML page in it, so thought it might be expedient to host the webchat client there. But now seems counter-intuitive that my webchat client is using DirectLine to send activities back to the same back-end that served it.

I had chosen the webchat client because I need to customise the appearance of the client. I also need the MVC app that serves the bot client to include Azure Active Directory B2C authentication (which it does). Users should see the webchat client before and after authentication but the bot back-end (handling the activities) needs to know whether the user is logged in and modify its behaviour accordingly (and I am struggling to achieve that part with DirectLine).

So my first question (ever on StackOverflow) is: With the Bot back-end and the webchat client front-end being hosted in the same, single Azure web app, is it necessary to use DirectLine, or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Relevant code in my Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;

    app.UseStaticFiles(); // to allow serving up the JS, CSS, etc., files.
    app.UseBotFramework(); // to add middleware to route webchat activity to the bot back-end code
    app.UseSession(); // to enable session state
    app.UseAuthentication(); // to enable authentication (in this case AAD B2C)
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); // to add MVC middleware with default route
}
```

Also in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
```

// standard code to add HttpContextAssessor, BotServices, BotConfigs and memory storage singletons ommitted for brevity ...

```
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))
        .AddCookie();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
        });


        // Create and add conversation state.
        var conversationState = new ConversationState(dataStore);
        services.AddSingleton(conversationState);

        var userState = new UserState(dataStore);
        services.AddSingleton(userState);

        services.AddBot<MyBot>(options =>
        {
            options.CredentialProvider = new SimpleCredentialProvider(endpointService.AppId, endpointService.AppPassword);
            options.ChannelProvider = new ConfigurationChannelProvider(Configuration);

            // Catches any errors that occur during a conversation turn and logs them to currently
            // configured ILogger.
            ILogger logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RucheBot>();
            options.OnTurnError = async (context, exception) =>
            {
                logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception}");
                await context.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.");
            };
        });

    }
```

My controller's Index method:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        string userId;
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string aadb2cUserId = User.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier").Value;
            Users.EnsureAccountExists(aadb2cUserId); // ensure account with given AAD identifier is know locally (by creating it if not)
            userId = $"ia_{aadb2cUserId}";
        }
        else
        {
            userId = $"na_{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        }


        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string directLineUrl = $"https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate";
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, directLineUrl);

        // TODO: put this in the config somewhere
        var secret = "<the secret code from my bot's DirectLine channel config in the Azure portal>";
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", secret);
        string jsonUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { User = new { Id = userId } });
        request.Content = new StringContent(jsonUser, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        string token = string.Empty;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DirectLineToken>(body).token;
        }

        var config = new ChatConfig()
        {
            Token = token,
            UserId = userId,
        };

        return View(config);
    }
```

And finally the code in the associated view:

```
<div id="webchat"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
...
        /// Called asynchronously during the page load
        function renderWebChat( withSound )
        {
            var webchatOptions =
            {
                directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine( { secret: '@Model.Token'} ),
                userID: '@Model.UserId'
            };

            if ( withSound )
            {
                webchatOptions.webSpeechPonyfillFactory = window.WebChat.createBrowserWebSpeechPonyfillFactory();
            }

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat( webchatOptions, document.getElementById( 'webchat' ) );

            document.querySelector( '#webchat > *' ).focus();
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the answers yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with Nicolas R a little bit. When it comes to directly accessing your bot, you might like to have a look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline

There's also the option of [hosting a bot in the browser](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_es6/01.a.browser-echo), which I think may facilitate the sort of direct communication you're looking for.

Comment: Good points. But the 1st one is an unofficial package and I'm not sure it is a direction that Microsoft would encourage (but as you are in the support team from Microsoft, you must have more information about that).

Comment: I did share your hesitation and I only posted this answer after discussing it with my superiors to make sure it's okay. The offline-directline package was also developed by a Microsoft employee.

Comment: Kyle and Nicolas thanks for informative answers :-) Would I be correct in thinking that the offline-directline option allows direct communication with the hosted bot while leaving open communication through the standard channels (DL, Skype, etc.)? Also does the browser-hosted option obviate the bot framework, therefore not allow communication with the bot through other channels (other than in the browser that's hosting it)?

Comment: @JohnChurch - I have not tried offline-directline so I will need to look into it a bit in order to answer your question. And I presume you would not be able to connect to a browser-hosted bot through another channel, though I have not tried that either.

Comment: @JohnChurch - I've done some testing on my local machine and here's what I've found. Both of these options can probably still expose an endpoint that standard channels can access, but you'd be missing out when it comes to authentication and it sounds like you want your bot to be secure. The browser-hosted option does not obviate the Bot Framework since you can still use the Bot Builder SDK and that's part of the Bot Framework. Also, it turns out offline-directline works with C# bots just fine, so I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Long question, but the answer will be a lot shorter!

> So my first question (ever on StackOverflow) is: With the Bot back-end
>   and the webchat client front-end being hosted in the same, single
>   Azure web app, is it necessary to use DirectLine, or is there a
>   simpler way of doing this?

Yes, it is necessary. In fact, all the channels types are using the Bot Connector to communicate with your backend (your bot code), there is no direct access possible. There are a lot of reasons for that, one is for example the billing!